# Filter Yelp API results

Tags: iphone, ios, yelp

I have been trying to integrate yelp with an application.

Let's say I want to see all the italian restaurants at a place. According to the yelp api, the query should be

```
http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=restaurants&category=italian&place=san+jose
```

But from the results that I see, I see hardly any italian restaurants. Is there any other way to query the api?

Comment: I get the error response "One or more parameters are missing in request", so the problem is with your request.

Comment: Did you have all your credentials in place?

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter missing error. You need to add the id and oath_consumer_key. You are seeing no results because the query is incorrect

Oath key:
http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/authentication

ID is the yelp ID for the business:
http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business

Comment: Actually I am getting the results, the problem is I am not getting relevant results. In the above case, I am not getting italian restaurants. I am getting a bunch of restaurants which are not necessarily italian.

Comment: I have all the keys required to make a request. I have just not put it specifically in the request.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your parameters are incorrect; it should be:

```
https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=restaurants&category_filter=italian&location=san+jose
```

https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api